# What will happen if we apply Gradient Ascent?

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, gradient-descent

I have built a simple neural network on MNIST, but instead of moving toward the opposite direction of gradients, I moved in the same direction of it just by applying( pytorch ):

```py
For m in model.parameters():
  m.weight.grad *= -1
```

I just wanted to know what will happen in prediction. I got these results as confusion matrix.
Are we able to interpret the results?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, let's think it through: You're calculating the gradient at each step, which points you in the direction of lower loss. Then, you're reversing the direction, going in the opposite direction, away from whatever minima the gradient was pointing you towards.

If you're near the global minimum, this means that you're moving further from the best solution with every step. If you're near local minima, you'll move away from them, which may or may not move you in the direction of the global minimum. It doesn't really matter, though, because if it does move you such that the nearest minima is now the global minimum, at the next step you'll start moving away from it.

To put it simply, you're designing a model that is as wrong as possible. This is even more clear looking at the confusion matrix, where you see that the model is returning the same class for every sample, and not even the highest frequency class (you get 982 correct, largest class is 1135).

The model is performing worse than the simplest possible baseline, selecting the majority class.

Comment: Actually, it is clear that it is worse than a random selection but, the question is why all prediction is 4? Also how it classifies each 4 correctly?

Comment: It's not necessarily answerable *why* that's what it landed on. And it's getting that class correct because it's always predicting that class. It's like how a broken clock is right twice a day, not because it's actually right but because it looks like it's right sometimes.

Comment: I just did that for fun to play arount neural networks

Comment: I understand, that's why my answer explained what's happening instead of just telling you not to do it ;)